# ILIAS plugin development

Tags: php, plugins

I'm working with a learning management system called [ILIAS](http://www.ilias.de/docu/); trying to develop a plugin for the PersonalDesktopHook [pdhk] plugin slot.

Sadly I'm stuck with deploying the simplest plugin:

1. Created a directory for my plugin:

> ilias/Customizing/global/plugins/Services/PersonalDesktop/PluginName

2. Created a plugin.php file as described in the documentation (with matching id, etc.).
3. Created a classes/class.ilPluginNamePlugin.php file containing a ilPluginNamePlugin extending the abstract ilPersonalDesktopHookPlugin class located in

> ilias/Services/PersonalDesktop/classes/class.ilPersonalDesktopHookPlugin.php

Still my plugin isn't showing up in the Services/PersonalDesktop component menu (Administration).

Did I miss something or is the plugin development documentation out of date?

(I followed the ILIAS development guide's "[Implementing Plugins](http://www.ilias.de/docu/goto_docu_pg_27031_42.html)" section.)

Comment: Check the file permissions (`chmod`).

Comment: ... and correct path name.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is late, but this seems to be a common issue in ilias plugin development. The following things should be checked:

- Is the path really correct (including case of the file/folders name). In this case it isn't, it should be: ./Customizing/global/plugins/Services/PersonalDesktop/PersonalDesktopHook/PluginName . If you are unsure consult: https://www.ilias.de/docu/goto_docu_pg_27031_42.html or the xml of the corresponding service/module, in this case: ./Services/PersonalDesktop/service.xml
- Check that you have a plugin.php file with the correct $id set (in this case: pdsk).
- Check that your webserver has read permissions for you plugin to be listed in the administration.